# System Verilog Loops

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, cpu-architecture, hdl, yosys

Im currently working on the Shift-Add Algorithm (32x32 bit Multiplication) in System Verilog. System Verilog cant find any error and my code is working correctly according to GTKwave. When I synthesize my circuit with yosys, Latches will be added. And that is the Problem. I dont want Latches in my Circuit. Heres my Code:

```
module multiplier(
  input logic         clk_i,
  input logic         rst_i,
  input logic         start_i,
  input logic [31:0]  a_i,
  input logic [31:0]  b_i,
  output logic        finished_o,
  output logic [63:0] result_o
);

typedef enum logic [1:0] { STATE_A, STATE_B} state_t;
  state_t state_p, state_n;
logic [63:0] fin_res;
logic [63:0] tmp;
logic rst_flag;
integer i;


always @(posedge clk_i or posedge rst_i) begin
  if (rst_i == 1'b1) begin
    state_p <= STATE_B;
  end
  else begin
    state_p <= state_n;
  end
end


always @(*)begin
  state_n = state_p;
  case (state_p)
    STATE_A: if (start_i == 0) state_n = STATE_B;
    STATE_B: if (start_i == 1) state_n = STATE_A;
    default: state_n = state_p;
  endcase
end


always @(*) begin
  case (state_p)
    STATE_A: begin
      rst_flag = 1;
      fin_res = 0;
      finished_o = 0;
      tmp = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
        if (a_i[i] == 1'b1) begin
          tmp = b_i;
          tmp = tmp << i;
          fin_res = fin_res + tmp;
        end
      end
    end
    STATE_B: begin 
      result_o = fin_res;
      if (rst_flag == 1) finished_o = 1;
      if (start_i == 1) finished_o = 0;
    end
    default: begin
        finished_o = 0;
        result_o = 0;
    end
  endcase
end
endmodule
```

After spending 2 days only with debugging and not finding any mistake I would like to ask if u could help me. I am assigning every output (at least I think so). So where is my mistake? Is it the for loop? But what would be wrong with it? Thanks in advance for your help :)

Some useful Information for the Code-Snippet: start_i is the starting signal. If this is set to 1 the multiplication should be started. finished_o is the finish flag. If this is set to 1 the CPU will know that the computation is completed. a_i and b_i are the inputs which should be multiplied. result_o is the result of the multiplication which can be read when finished_o is set to 1.

According to yosys i get the following latches:

64 *DLATCH_N*

64 *DLATCH_P*

I think something may be wrong with fin_res in the for loop cause that logic variable is exactly 64 bits long as are the Latches

Comment: But you did code a latch with the second case statement.  e.g., you do not assign *finished_o* in every case (you use 'if' with no else there).

Comment: Also with `rst_flag`, since it is not assigned if `state_p` is not `STATE_A`

Comment: Yeah but even fixing these, doesnt change anything regarding the latches.

Comment: Ok I fixed it. Sometimes it is better to rewrite the whole code than searching for the bugs... Thx for the help guys :)

Comment: and there is also `fin_res` and probably `tmp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment you have a bunch of variables which are not assigned in the second case statement causing synthesis to generate latches. To avoid it you need to assign all the vars in all branches of the case statement and conditional statements recursively.

However, if there is a default value you can assign to all of them, you can use a pattern similar to the one from the second always block, just assigning default values before the 'case' statement. This way you do not even need the *default* clause and you can get rid of it in the second always block as well.

```
always @(*) begin
  // set default values
  rst_flag = 0;
  fin_res = 0;
  finished_o = 0;
  tmp = 0;
  result_o = 0;

  case (state_p)
    STATE_A: begin
       rst_flag = 1;

      for (i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
        if (a_i[i] == 1'b1) begin
          tmp = b_i;
          tmp = tmp << i;
          fin_res = fin_res + tmp;
        end
      end
    end
    STATE_B: begin 
      result_o = fin_res;

      // are you sure that you do not need a latch here?
      if (rst_flag == 1) finished_o = 1;
      if (start_i == 1) finished_o = 0;
    end
    // you do not need 'default' here.
  endcase
end
```

My fixes will cause combinational behavior and should get rid of latches in synthesis, but it does not look like they will behave as you expected. It looks like you *really* need a *latches* here.

1. *rst_flag* must be a latch. You set it in STATE_A and use it in STATE_B. It has to keep the value between states. This is a latch behavior.
2. In STATE_B you change *finished_o* only if some of conditions met. What happens if the *rst_flag* and *start_i* are both 0. do you want finished_o to be 0 or the previous value? In the latter case you need a latch.
3. How about *fin_res* ? What do you want to do with it in other states? keep previous value (latch) or have a default value (no latch).

...

Comment: Yeah you are right. Latches were necessary in my Code. I rewrote the whole Code so I dont have any Latches now. Thx for helping :)